# Outlook mailitem missing blank ConversationIndex and ConversationID

Tags: vba, outlook, mailitem

I have some code that has been working until recently that used the mailitem ConversationIndex to track emails.

All of a sudden all mailitems are being created with blank indexes and IDs.

```
myMail = CreateItemFromTemplate(sTemplatePath)
debug.print mymail.ConversationIndex
```

Outputs blank!!!

Any ideas what I've screwed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot expect the conversation related properties to be populated immediately after an item is created. It is reliably populated only after the item is sent.